# Get JSON from local JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

good afternoon. I'm developing an app that can get a JSON from local (manifest.json). I want to get this file from JavaScript and then read it. But I have a problem, I cant call this file. How can I?

```
var urlJSON = new XMLHttpRequest("manifes.json").toString;
var dataJSON = JSON.parse(urlJSON);

alert(dataJSON.name);
```

Comment: First do `console.log(urlJSON)` to see what actually contains this variable.

Comment: i think your spelling for filename is wrong `var urlJSON = new XMLHttpRequest("manifest.json").toString;`

Comment: That is not how you use `XMLHttpRequest`, [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). Also what do you mean by "local"? The user's hard drive? That cannot be done, without the user selecting it through some process like a file input

Answer (score 2):

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'manifest.json';
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText));
  }
  if (xmlhttp.status == 404) {}
};
xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Or run chrome with arguments `--allow-file-access-from-files`
Or download and create server for your app

Comment: It says "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/ferna/Desktop/The%20pong/manifest.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource".